# Forward slash in stored procedure parameter not recognised

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm making this stored procedure call:

```
exec sp_executesql N'EXEC MyStoredProcedure 
     @MyId = @0, @MyVarField = @1', 
     N'@0 int, @1 nvarchar(4000)',
     @0=2, @1='lll/kkk'
```

The stored procedure is just a simple select, looking for `MyVarField = 'lll/kkk'`, but the `/` in the parameter seems to break it... it can't find the db row anyway.

If I pass in `'ffflll'` then it finds the row which contains `lllkkk`, just doesn't find it when there's a `/` in it. What's that about?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[MyStoredProcedure]
@MyId int,
@MyVarField  varchar
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE VarField = @VarField
END
```

What do I need to do to the stored procedure to make it accept the / as part of a `varchar`?

Comment: Can you show your stored procedure code?

Comment: Why are you EXECing an EXEC anyway?  Why not just `exec MyStoredProcedure @MyId=2, @MyVarField='lll/kkk'`?

Comment: ah, the code is generated by PetaPoco - I've just copied exactly as it runs it

Comment: really strange issue that still ocurrs on 2017 server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try making your parameter match the same type as the statement (and presumably the underlying column), and giving it a length:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[MyStoredProcedure]
    @MyId int,
    @MyVarField NVARCHAR(4000)
AS
...
```

I don't think the failure currently has anything to do with the slash. Try this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.foo
  @bar VARCHAR
AS
  PRINT @bar;
GO

EXEC dbo.foo '12345';
```

For some background, please read:

- [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length)

Comment: It was the lenght on the nvarchar thanks...very strange that it worked without the /, hey ho

Answer (score -2):

Forward slash (“/” ) is the shortcut for RUN command (like “go” in mysql or sqlserver).

http://power2build.wordpress.com/2011/12/09/forward-slash-in-sqlplus/

Comment: Isn't sqlplus an oracle thing?

Comment: try using double forward slashes //

Comment: No, it doesn't.  `/` does not mean anything special to sqlcmd or sp_executesql.  Its only meaning is whatever is given to it by T-SQL syntax, which is perfectly fine with it being unescaped in strings.

Comment: yes, you're right, is doesn't include mssql. seems to be an oracle issue. http://powerbuildev.wordpress.com/tag/oracle/

Comment: No. This is wrong